# I have a ViewBag value from Controller which changes my page-title name

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**so this is my Create.cshtml and controller code here**

and this my button link:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Loan">@ViewBag.EntityState</button>
```

when its new record being created then my page title name look like this (Create Loan) but when its being  updated then my page title name is (Update Loan).

so what i wanna know is that what i'm using now is working perfectly.`ViewData["Title"] =string.Concat(ViewBag.EntityState," Loan");` is there any other trick or way which is better than this one or my way doing is fine.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] =string.Concat(ViewBag.EntityState," Loan");
ViewData["CurrentPage"] = "Loan";
```

}

**and this is my controller code here**

```
public IActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.DeductionTypes = ConfigValues.GetConfigValues("HR", "Deduction Type");
        ViewBag.Accounts = LoanRepo.GetAccounts();
        if (id == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.EntityState = "Create";
            var model = new HRLoan(); 
            TempData["LoanNo"] = LoanRepo.GetLoanNo(id);
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.EntityState = "Update";
            HRLoan loan = LoanRepo.GetById(id);
            //loan.BankAccounts = LoanRepo.GetBankAccounts();
            TempData["LoanNo"] = loan.LoanNo;
            // ViewBag.FamilyDetail = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EmployeeRepo.GetEmployeeFamilyMembers(id));
            return View(loan);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming code from the controller is your get method right?

Comment: And are you asking of a way to better set the Value of your Page Title?

Comment: @IsmailUmar  yes... is there a better way to set the page-title-name dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean programatically in C# Code?

Comment: @IsmailUmar .. nah! its fine i think the way you suggested its also fine. thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO what you can do since you are setting the value of ViewBag.EntityState from your controller.

You can use string interpolation like this

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = $"{ViewBag.EntityState} Loan";
     ViewData["CurrentPage"] = "Loan";
}
```